# Terraform init too slow on installing hashicorp/aws

Tags: terraform, network-monitoring

It takes a few minutes to install the following provider but installs modules and other providers quickly. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27379) on GitHub for this but no steps for troubleshooting.
`Installing hashicorp/aws v4.61.0...`

I have installed Terraform through `tfenv` and my network connectivity fine with other hosts but the issue with this provider is consistent.

Comment: find its slow too. I dont understand why it also can't use some serialisation of version inputs to determine if it can avoid init again when its already been done and cached.